# how to automatically filter and seperate the array of object data if number of objects have the common value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
  const mixedData = [{name :'Darci' , skill : 'python'},{name :'Darci' , skill : 'javascript'},{name :'Darci' , skill : 'react js'},{name :'Brooke' , skill : 'Photoshop'},{name :'Brooke' , skill : 'Indesign'},{name :'John' , skill : 'mangoDB'},{name :'john' , skill : 'mySQL'}]
```

**but i want output like this**

```
const Data = [{name: 'Darci' , skill : ['python' , 'javascript' , 'react js']},
              {name: 'Brooke' , skill : ['Photoshop' , 'Indesign']},
              {name: 'Jhon' , skill : ['mangoDB' , 'mySQL']},
]
```

*but i dont want to hard code by filter method like below code*

```
const finalArray = mixedData.filter(e=> e.name === 'Darci' ?{...} : {...}

)
```

no matter how may unique values in object filter please anyone help me out of this solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the result using `Array.reduce()` to group the skills according to the user name:

```js
const mixedData = [{name :'Darci' , skill : 'python'},{name :'Darci' , skill : 'javascript'},{name :'Darci' , skill : 'react js'},{name :'Brooke' , skill : 'Photoshop'},{name :'Brooke' , skill : 'Indesign'},{name :'John' , skill : 'mangoDB'},{name :'john' , skill : 'mySQL'}]

const result = Object.values(mixedData.reduce((acc, { name, skill }) => { 
    acc[name] ||= { name, skill: [] };
    acc[name].skill.push(skill);
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: -Terry Lennox  thank you very much really satisfied with your answer

Comment: i know how to do with for loop but leads bit time to take convert, i really like your array.reducer answer thank you very much - Terry Lennox